# Extraer valores de una serie python

Tags: python, python-3.x, array, pandas

Tengos dos datraframe una llamado `prueba` (contiene 28 filas):

```
        Metropolitan area                     NHL  Population (2016 est.)[8]
0           New York City  RangersIslandersDevils                   20153634
1             Los Angeles              KingsDucks                   13310447
2  San Francisco Bay Area                  Sharks                    6657982
3                 Chicago              Blackhawks                    9512999
4       Dallas–Fort Worth                   Stars                    7233323
5        Washington, D.C.                Capitals                    6131977
6            Philadelphia                  Flyers                    6070500
7                  Boston                  Bruins                    4794447
8  Minneapolis–Saint Paul                    Wild                    3551036
9                  Denver               Avalanche                    2853077
```

Y otro llamado `prueba2` (contiene 30 filas):

```
                    team   W   L
1   Tampa Bay Lightning*  54  23
2         Boston Bruins*  50  20
3   Toronto Maple Leafs*  49  26
4       Florida Panthers  44  30
5      Detroit Red Wings  30  39
6     Montreal Canadiens  29  40
7        Ottawa Senators  28  43
8         Buffalo Sabres  25  45
10  Washington Capitals*  49  26
11  Pittsburgh Penguins*  47  29
```

El objetivo es buscar los equipos de `prueba['NHL]` en `prueba2['team']` Creé este código:

```
for citie in prueba['NHL']:
    y = prueba2[prueba2['team'].str.contains(citie)]['team']
    result.append(y.values)
```

pero me genera la lista de esa forma:

```
[array([], dtype=object),
 array([], dtype=object),
 array(['San Jose Sharks*'], dtype=object),
 array(['Chicago Blackhawks'], dtype=object),
 array(['Dallas Stars'], dtype=object),
 array(['Washington Capitals*'], dtype=object),
 array(['Philadelphia Flyers*'], dtype=object),
 array(['Boston Bruins*'], dtype=object),
 array(['Minnesota Wild*'], dtype=object),
 array(['Colorado Avalanche*'], dtype=object),
 array(['Florida Panthers'], dtype=object),
 array(['Arizona Coyotes'], dtype=object),
```

¿Cómo podría generar solo el nombre del equipo de prueba2['team'] sin que me genere un array dentro de la lista?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voy a crear dos `DataFrame` de ejemplo con lo que te está ocurriendo:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

puntos = np.random.randint(0, 70, 7)
win = np.random.randint(0, 70, 7)
loss = np.random.randint(0, 70, 7)

lista_equipos_coloquial = ["Madrid", "Barsa", "Lugo", "River", "Chicago", "Denver", "Arsenal"]
lista_equipos_oficial = ["Real Madrid", "Barsa FC", "Lugo FC", "River Plate", "Chicago Bulls", "Real Betis Balompie", "Badajoz FC"]


#Dataframes de ejemplo
df_poblacion = pd.DataFrame({"equipos":lista_equipos_coloquial,
                             "puntos":puntos,})

df_win_loss = pd.DataFrame({"equipos":lista_equipos_oficial,
                            "W": win,
                            "L": loss})
```

Perfecto ya tenemos el problema de una forma reproducible ¡Ahora vamos a resolverlo!

Yo lo resolvería creando una simple función y mapeandola por el `DataFrame` es así de sencillo:

```
#Imaginamos que no tenemos los equipos es una lista, los pasamos fácilmente
equipos_a_buscar = df_poblacion["equipos"].to_list()

def buscar_equipo(x):
    for nombre in equipos_a_buscar:
        if nombre in x:
            return x

df_win_loss["equipos"].map(buscar_equipo)
```

**Salida:**

```
0      Real Madrid
1         Barsa FC
2          Lugo FC
3      River Plate
4    Chicago Bulls
5             None
6             None
```

El método `.map()` de un `DataFrame` le va aplicando **a cada fila de la columna seleccionada** una función. En este caso yo me he creado la función `busca_equipo()` que hace la comprobación. Te explico paso por paso:

1. Pasamos todos los equipos de nuestro primer `DataFrame` a una lista con el método `to_list()`, y nos creamos la lista `equipos_a_buscar`
2. Creamos una función que se llama `buscar_equipo()` que contiene la lista anterior sobre la que va iterando, en el caso de que encuentre el nombre en dicha lista, nos devuelve el nombre
3. Aplicamos la función anterior a cada fila de la columna `equipos` del `DataFrame` primero, es decir `df_poblacion`

### Bonus extra

- No es recomedable, que llames a tus variables, dataframes, etc. Con nombres genéricos y sin significado, como son `prueba1`, `prueba2`, `prueba3`, etc. Esto induce a confusiones y a que el código sea menos legible **¡Los nombres de las variables están para representar lo que contienen dichas variables!**
- Pandas trata de imitar a `SQL` y  tiene sus propias funciones, métodos, clases, etc, por lo que es muy raro que tengas que usar bucles para resolver un problema. Si estás usando bucles **probablemente haya una forma más sencilla de resolverlo.**

Comment: Ok entiendo, y si quiero organizarlo por el mismo orden que esta en prueba1 , como lo haria?

Comment: Esto no lo habías puesto en la pregunta, pero una vez lo entiendes, solo tendrías que cambiar la variable `equipo_a_buscar` por la otra lista de equipos y la función `buscar_equipo()` para que busque  en `equipos_a_buscar` y por último aplicar el `map()` al Dataframe 1.